# How to hide some part of figure in pyplot plot_surface for better 3d figure in python?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, graphics

I am trying to plot a specific tours for my project where some of its specific edges and nodes are highlighted. In order to do this, I am using first `plot_surface` command to draw a torus and then I use `plot_wireframe` to highlight specific edges and nodes. So, here is my code:

```
    from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
    from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import *
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    from random import random, seed
    from matplotlib import cm
    from matplotlib import colors
    import matplotlib as mpl
    # mpl.rcParams['lines.linewidth'] = 5

    plt.hold(True)
    n = 30
    theta = np.linspace(0, 2.*np.pi, n)
    phi = np.linspace(0, 2.*np.pi, n)
    theta, phi = np.meshgrid(theta, phi)
    c, a = 2, 1
    x = (c + a*np.cos(theta)) * np.cos(phi)
    y = (c + a*np.cos(theta)) * np.sin(phi)
    z = a * np.sin(theta)
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    ax1.set_zlim(-2,2)
    ax1.scatter(x,y,z+0.001,color="black",s=1,marker='o')
    for i in range(n):
        if(i%3==0):
            color='yellowgreen'
        elif(i%3==1):
            color="silver"
        else:
            color="cyan"
        ax1.plot_surface(x[i:i+2], y[i:i+2], z[i:i+2], rstride=3, cstride=1, edgecolors=color,color=color,alpha=0.4,shade=False)
    ax1.plot_wireframe(x, y, z,rstride=3, cstride=1,color='r',alpha=0.4)
    ax1.view_init(36, 26)
    plt.show()
```

This is the figure I get:

[image]

As you can see, the back part of my image is visible when you see it from front shot and this makes the figure less clear. I want to make the back part of it invisible from front shot in any direction. in other words, I want to get sth similar to this image(I have used photoshop on my first image to get this one but I want to make my code do it automatically for me):

[image]

I would really appreciate if anyone could help me  to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you set your translucency value to "1"?

Replace

```
alpha=0.4
```

with

```
alpha=1
```

in your

```
ax1.plot_surface
```

Comment: The answer is not correct. I do not know if you have tested your answer, but it is not going to make any difference as I just checked it.

Comment: Did you also set your wireframe alpha to 1? I'm sure you didn't. Your plot clearly shows translucency

Comment: Sorry, did check it now, you have to generate a surface from your wireframe and fill this, you can't set no translucency to a wireframe..